# Generic with lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda, dbcontext

I'm trying to create "some kind" of custom "DbContext" for very specific application which uses MongoDb. And I faced with one problem:

**How did DbSet know of DbContext existence?**

I mean, when I write

```
public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

in my DbContext, how the DbSet instance gets the reference to the DbContext class? Via reflection?

But when I was digging into [EntityFramework source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) I faced another problem

```
public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class => _setInitializer.Value.CreateSet<TEntity>(this);
```

In this expression I cannot understand what does lambda expression in "where" clause. Could someone enlighten me?

**UPD**
Every time when I call my DbSet property in DbContext

```
public class BlogPostContextContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

The DbSet calls the DbContext and it produces necessary manipulations over the data.
My question is: how DbSet gets the reference to the DbContext.
I'm asking about underlying communication between DbSet and DbContext.

Thanks in advance.
Excuse my english.
Ivan Talalaev

Comment: it just means that `TEntity` must be a class - it constraints the generic parameter - usually you use this with an interface, but there are some special values as `new` (needs a parameterless ctor so that you can create values of the generic type), ...

Comment: Lambda Expression syntax is new in C# 6(Expression-Bodied Methods), http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/05/14/c.net-little-wonders-expression-bodied-members-in-c-6.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot understand what does lambda expression in "where" clause.

The method declaration has two parts. The first is a generic type constraint:

```
where TEntity : class
```

This means that any type used in the place of `TEntity` needs to be a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The second part is an [Expression-bodied function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx):

```
=> _setInitializer.Value.CreateSet<TEntity>(this);
```

Which is a C# 6.0 feature.  If your method is a one-liner, it can be declared *like* a Lambda Expression. It simply means that each time you call `Set`, it will invoke the one line "body" of the method. The compiler will turn it into a named method "behind the scenes".

> How did DbSet know of DbContext existence?

It doesn't know about it *directly*. `DbContext` represents your database, `DbSet` represents a table in that database. When you're manipulating your `DbSet`, it implicitly holds a reference to it's underlying `DbContext` and adds it's entities via the context.

Comment: "It simply means that each time you call Set." and..?

Comment: @YairNevet Not sure what happend. Fixed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks a lot for you answer. Do you have any Idea about DbContext?

Comment: @User I'm not sure I understand the question about `DbContext`. Could you elaborate? I mean, you inherit from `DbContext`, don't you?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes I Inherited from DbContext, but my question about communication between DbSet and DbContext. I've updated my question, could you look at it, if you please.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my last part of question.
According to [this](http://kataribe.naist.jp/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/12a92111971e861fd00ac53f6dc978c95bdd2aa6/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbSet%60.cs) and [this](http://kataribe.naist.jp/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/12a92111971e861fd00ac53f6dc978c95bdd2aa6/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbContext.cs) EntityFramework 6 (not sure about [new EF7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework)) 
DbSet keep reference `_context` to the DbContext and uses it to Add or Remove entities.

In turn DbContext some how (possibly via reflection) sets that references `_context` in all its encapsulated fields of type DbSet at time of cunstructor call.